# Problem in adding raster layer from arcpy

Tags: raster, arcpy

I am using the following code to add the raster layer using arcpy in arcmap

```
def AddRasterLayer(path,layerName):
    layer=os.path.join(path,'new'+str(layerName)+'.lyr')
    mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,'*')[0]
    arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(Raster(layerName),layer)
    newlayer=arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,newlayer,'TOP')
    new_name=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,newlayer,df)
    new_name[0].name=str(layerName)
    del layer
```

After using this function raster layer is added to my current data frame. But when I am using any other tools it is showing as in the image

[image]

it is showing all the tree structure of the layer. Why is it so ? I need only the layers name to be displayed here.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are giving the layer the full path name when you create the Raster Layer.
This is what you are doing:

> arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(Raster(layerName),layer)

The output argument "layer" is a full file path. What you should change it to is this:

> arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(Raster(layerName),layerName)

This will give you your required result.

I think you are trying to  create a layer '.lyr' file using the following code: `layer=os.path.join(path,'new'+str(layerName)+'.lyr')`

This will not work, to do this please read the following link:

[Save To Layer File (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000070000000)